# Problem with apples push notification services

Tags: c#, iphone, apple-push-notifications

Hello I am using Apple's push notification .

My web services are in c sharp  .I used [Push notification](http://arashnorouzi.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/sending-apple-push-notifications-in-asp-net-part-1/)  code. Every thing is going fine. With out error.  but why My messages are  not delivered to iphone application,

I am using development certificate. same thing is working properly from php script. I am getting log that message is delivered but not getting on iphone.. Also checked sandbox. Url for testing

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: Have you created a socket correctly and writing the data into it? Some checkpoints are - your private key and certificate to sign the response.

Comment: Check weather your iPhone side is correct. Registering for APNs, getting proper Device token like wise.

Comment: But php code is working fine...

Comment: You need to provide more information.  Are you using an ad-hoc install or an install through xcode?  Do you have your correct certificates, are you using the correct Apple notification server (sandbox or production), are you absolutely sure your notification message to their server is correctly formatted?

Comment: Are you actually registering for remote notifications on the device using `- (void)registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationType)types` and then taking the token returned by the delegate method `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken` and passing it to your server?

Comment: I used [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
  (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

Comment: Provide code details what you are doing in C#. However check these links, might be useful http://arashnorouzi.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/sending-apple-push-notifications-in-asp-net-part-1/
http://code.google.com/p/apns-sharp/

Comment: I am using same like word press example